# Jquery onclick() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying to get this onclick to work, but even after checking a bunch of other answers, no success, here is the code.

```
<section id="tryit" class="tryit bg-primary text-center">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <h2 class="section-heading">Try It Out!</h2>
                  Enter Some Text Here:<br>
                  <textarea name='Status'> yo</textarea>
                  <input type='button' id="submit" value='Status Update'/>
                  <script>
                  $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#submit").click(function() {
                      alert("click");
                    });
                  });
                  </script>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The onclick just doesn't get called, any solutions?

EDIT
The library is added in the head tag. It might be that i'm testing from file://, is it possible that that is the problem?

p.s. might be a noob error

Comment: Your code is fine. it should work. Are you getting any error in `console`?

Comment: browser's console will let you know better.....!

Comment: have you invluded jQuery library file  ?

Comment: Your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/f1ecud7x/. Have you actually included jQuery in the page? Check the console for errors

Comment: it works fine. check for jquery included or not

Comment: inculde jQuery library to your html template

Comment: Jquery was included, I really don'tunderstand whats going wrong

Answer (score 1):

This work on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dbnkv2sm/)

Maybe jQuery is not called in your html :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Have you got an error in your console ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a JQuery code, you should import JQuery library, and since your code in inline with html, your jquery plugin should be called in < head > section.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#submit").click(function() {
     alert("click");
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="tryit" class="tryit bg-primary text-center">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <h2 class="section-heading">Try It Out!</h2>
        Enter Some Text Here:<br>
        <textarea name='Status'> yo</textarea>
        <input type='button' id="submit" value='Status Update'/>
                          
     </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</section>
```